# VBA index/match blank cell

Tags: vba, indexing, match

I have a list of accounts & codes, and would like to populate a column with results from a different sheet using index match. I can get it to work using the formula: =index(rngB,match(BCode,rngM,0),55)

but can't translate it to vba. I have tried:

```
sub compare() 

Dim BudgetResult As Long
Dim var1 As Long
Dim rngB, rngM As Range
Dim CompSH, ActSH, BudSH As Worksheet
Dim BCode As Variant

Set CompSH = Sheets.Add(After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count))
Set ActSH = Sheets(2)
Set BudSH = Sheets(3)
Set rngB = BudSH.Range("B11:BF50")
Set rngM = BudSH.Range("B:B")
Set BCode = CompSH.Range("A2")

BudSH.Select
Range("B10:E76").Select
Selection.Copy
CompSH.Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Range("F1").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Budget"
Range("F2").Select

With Application.WorksheetFunction

var1 = .Match(BCode, rngM, 0)
BudgetResult = .Index(rngB, var1, 55)

End With
```

I get a blank cell. no result in the sheet.
Also, I don't know how to continue it down. Can anyone help?

Comment: are you set on translating the Excel Formula into VBA ? if you already decided to use VBA, why not use it's extra capabilities ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you may be after something like follows

```
Option Explicit

Sub compare()
    Dim rngB As Range, rngM As Range, cell As Range
    Dim CompSH As Worksheet, ActSH As Worksheet, BudSH As Worksheet
    Dim AW As WorksheetFunction: Set AW = Application.WorksheetFunction

    Set CompSH = Sheets.Add(After:=Sheets(Sheets.count))
    Set ActSH = Sheets("ActSH") 'Sheets(2)
    Set BudSH = Sheets("BudSH") 'Sheets(3)

    With BudSH
        Set rngB = .Range("B11:BF50") '<--| warning: your "index" range has 40 rows
        Set rngM = .Range("B:B")
        .Range("F1").Value = "Budget"
        .Range("B10:E76").Copy CompSH.Range("A1") '<--| warning: your "copied" range has 67 rows
    End With

    With CompSH
        For Each cell In .Range("A2", .Cells(.Rows.count, 1).End(xlUp))
            cell.Offset(, 5).Value = AW.Index(rngB, AW.Match(cell, rngM, 0), 55) '<--| this will error when trying to access from 'rngB' range 41th rows on
        Next
    End With
End Sub
```

where you only have to adjust the range sizes in the statements marked with `<--| Warning...`